# Fatal error: Class 'DrupalDefaultEntityController' not found in comment.module

Tags: updating

I'm trying to update the Drupal Core of a website, specifically from 7.65 to 7.67.
I've followed the instructions from here. After the process, I've try to access the website without luck, because I'm getting the following error: `Fatal error: Class 'DrupalDefaultEntityController' not found in /var/www/html/modules/comment/comment.module on line 1698`

I've tried to run the `update.php` file and clearing the cache from the db several times, without fixing the error. I've also tried to update from 7.65 to 7.66, but the problem persists.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried to follow the instructions written [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) suggested by the user [sivani](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/85013/sivani). Here is the message I am getting:

```
DRUPAL_ROOT is /Users/DamianFox/tests/drupal-website/website.<br/>
Bootstrapping to DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION<br/>
<h1>Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.</h1><h2>Original</h2><p>PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /Users/DamianFox/tests/drupal-website/website/includes/lock.inc).</p><h2>Additional</h2><p>PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in system_list() (line 165 of /Users/DamianFox/tests/drupal-website/website/includes/module.inc).</p><hr />%
```

Comment: Is `/var/www/html/includes/entity.inc` present and readable by the web server?

Comment: It should be readable by the web server. I've checked the permissions and I've got this: `-rw-r--r--@`

Comment: Ok, so it's (probably) either that, which assuming MacOS you can clear with `xattr -c /path/to/entity.inc`, or something's gone wrong with the only other module that usually has any dealings with that file beyond a core install and update: the Entity API module. It's difficult to guess further without access to the server unfortunately

Comment: Ok. I tried the `xattr`, but it didn't work. I'm running the Drupal website in a Docker container. Maybe it has something to do with `yml` files?

Comment: just follow this instruction http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild . I hope this will help for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found out that the problem might be generated from `entity.inc` inside the `includes` folder. 
Therefore, I tried to put back the previous `entity.inc` (from the 7.65 installation); subsequently, I run the `update.php` script, and after another refresh, the website is finally accessible. 
I done few more tests to check if there are warnings or errors, but everything seems to work fine, so somehow I got it sorted.

Answer (score -1):

Try drush rr --fire-bazooka and see if that helps